# Is there a way to list a model inside another in Django admin?

Tags: django, list, admin

Given the following models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Company(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Category(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How to list the companies inside country, and add/edit in another page?
The same with Company and Category.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? Are you looking on how to make an admin form or how to display data on the admin page?

Comment: I want to display a list on the Country form with a list of Companies, where I can click a Company and edit in another page. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: And all of this inside the Django admin, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.